# help with logic

Tags: logic

I have a system where a user has to review a task. A task can have comments associated with it.

There are two ways of completing the task. By pressing buttons called 'completed with comments' or 'completed without comments'.

My logic is that there should be just one button 'completed' because the system should be able to work out if there are comments on the task or not

But!
For legal reasons the user has to be seen to have manually declared they have pressed one of the buttons, the logic being 'yes i confirm this task has comments/does not have comments on it'.

My question: is the human confirmation needed?

Comment: I agree with StudentX, although to add, depending on the legal situations you could also just add on the page or in the TOS. "By clicking 'completed' you consent to any comments made blah blahh" so that they don't have to click a checkbox everytime or have two buttons. But of course that is only applicable if it fits your legal needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a legal issue, then you need user's consent before submitting the form. What you can do instead of having 2 buttons is, have a single button 'completed' along with a checkbox which says something like..

> I have read and understand the legal sides of the task